# Spring RestDocs - document links in child documents?

Tags: spring-restdocs

How can I document links in child documents using Spring REST Docs?

Given the following JSON document:

```
{
  "links": {
    "alpha": "http://example.com/alpha",
    "beta": "http://example.com/beta"
  }
}
```

I can document the `links` by implementing a custom [LinkExtractor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/blob/1.0.x/spring-restdocs-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/restdocs/hypermedia/LinkExtractor.java) as suggested in the [reference docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/1.0.x/reference/html5/#documenting-your-api-hypermedia-link-formats) (I have working implementation that is very similar to the [HalLinkExtractor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/blob/1.0.x/spring-restdocs-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/restdocs/hypermedia/HalLinkExtractor.java)):

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/"))
    .andDo(document("root-resource",
        links(customLinkExtractor(),
            linkWithRel("alpha").description("Link to the Alpha resource"),
            linkWithRel("beta").description("Link to the Beta resource")
        )
    ));
```

However, my JSON document contains `links` sub-documents in other places, e.g.

```
{
    "links": {
        "alpha": "http://example.com/alpha",
        "beta": "http://example.com/beta",
    },
    "foo": {
        "links": {
            "gamma": "https://gamma.com/",
            "delta": "https://delta.com/"
        }
    }
}
```

How can I document the `links` document associated with the `foo` sub-document? Ideally, I would like to do something like:

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/"))
    .andDo(document("root-resource",
        links(customLinkExtractor(),
            linkWithRel("alpha").description("Link to the Alpha resource"),
            linkWithRel("beta").description("Link to the Beta resource")
        ),
        links(jsonPath("$.foo"), 
            customLinkExtractor(),
            linkWithRel("gamma").description("Link to the Gamma resource"),
            linkWithRel("delta").description("Link to the Delta resource")
        )
    ));
```

Naturally, this does not work since there is no `jsonPath(..)` method. What other options are available?

I guess that the same problem occurs if you are using the `HalLinkExtractor` and attempt to document links in the `_embedded` sub-document (see the example in the [draft-kelly-json-hal](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-kelly-json-hal-07#section-6)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're on the right track with a custom link extractor. Rather than trying to use a separate `jsonPath` method, why not add that capability to the custom extractor? You could then tell it where to look for the links. For example:

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/"))
    .andDo(document("root-resource",
        links(customLinkExtractor("$.links", "$.foo.links"),
            linkWithRel("alpha").description("Link to the Alpha resource"),
            linkWithRel("beta").description("Link to the Beta resource"),
            linkWithRel("gamma").description("Link to the Gamma resource"),
            linkWithRel("delta").description("Link to the Delta resource")
        )
    ));
```

Comment: I have updated my implementation like you suggested (with the slight variation that `customLinkExtractor()` always need the full jsonPath to the `links` document, e.g. `$.links`). However, now the problem is that I only see the output of the `gamma` and `delta` links in the generated `root-resource`. Alternatively, if I delete the second `links()` method in your snippet above, I will just see the `alpha` and `beta` links and the test passes.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the fact that the second `links` call will overwrite the snippet produced by the first. I've updated my answer with an approach that will produce a single snippet with all the links.

Comment: No worries, I have this working now. One disadvantage with this approach is that it is no longer possible to verify which links belong to `$.links` and which belong to `$.foo.links`.

Comment: That's a good point. I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/issues/164) to explore making some improvements in this area